# Utilizando no SQL coalesce com Date

Tags: sql, firebird

Estou com a seguinte dúvida. No SQL seu fizer dessa forma funciona.

```
...and coalesce(tb_cadastro.cod_produto,'') = coalesce(:COD_PRODUTO, coalesce(tb_cadastro.cod_produto,'')) and ...
```

Onde o `COD_PRODUTO` é um integer, como eu faria se o campo é do tipo `DATE`? Tentei dessa forma, mas não estou conseguindo filtrar por uma data.

```
...and coalesce(cast(tb_cadastro.dt_pallet AS varchar(10)),'') = coalesce(:DT_PALLET, coalesce(cast(tb_cadastro.dt_pallet AS varchar(10)),''))
```

Comment: você já tentou usar isso dentro do select para ver o que ele retorna ?

Comment: Mas por que você está dando um `cast` para transformar o campo `date` em `varchar`? Se você transformar para `varchar`, creio que você teria que fazer com todos, mas você não está transformando o campo `DT_PALLET`.

Comment: Por favor Tiago, poste a solução do problema como uma resposta, ao invés de coloca-la diretamente na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido da seguinte maneira:

```
...and cast(coalesce(tb_cadastro.dt_pallet,'')as date) = coalesce(:DT_PALLET, cast(coalesce(tb_cadastro.dt_pallet,'') as date))
```